# File.OpenText method is not declared error

Tags: asp.net

I have a FileUpload control from which I need the path of a text file. After selecting the file, I need to open and read the data from the text file. For this, I used the following code to open the text file.

```
fp = File.OpenText(FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName);
```

This is working fine on my system. The FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName property gives the full path of the file. The File.OpenText(() method opens the selected file. But when I run my project in IIS, it gives the following error:

```
"File.OpenText is not declared."
```

The FileUpload2.PostedFile.FileName property is not retrieving the full path. It retrieves only the file name. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical client server issue. On your system it works, because you are the client and the server, but on IIS (I assume you mean IIS on a test/production server) it looks for the file on the IIS server system while you select the file on your system.

You should use the FileUpload2.PostedFile.InputStream property instead of the filename property.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File("x.txt");
if(f.exists())
{
     .....
}
```